# Сбросил настройки Mi Band Smart 4 и теперь он не реагирует ни на Mi Fit, ни на Amazafit

Tags: android, bluetooth

В общем, есть смарт-браслет Mi Band 4. Покупал в августе прошлого года. Авторизовался на Mi Fit, все прекрасно, все работало, потом мне захотелось просто переместить все данные на другой аккаунт, сделал что-то не то,сбросил браслет и он перестал подключаться к телефон у/аккаунту Mi fit (я даже авторизовался через другую учетную запись). Ну и я забил на него, через месяц я попытался устранить эту проблему, устранил через Amazafit, не понял как, но все заработало.

И недавно я во сне умудрился сбросить настройки браслета и теперь он  вообще не реагирует ни на Mi Fit, ни на Amazafit...

Что можно сделать?
*(в настройкаx bluetooth высвечивается)*

Comment: Это сайт для разработчиком и системных администраторов. По поводу устройств пишите на соответствующих форумах или в тех поддержку

Comment: Необходимо писать на сайт разработчика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепрошить можно или сделать хард ресет

https://meeband2.info/faq/sbros-nastroek-mi-band-4